# android how to return the name and id from ImageView object

Tags: android, imageview

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

How can I return the name (of the image) fron img? What about the id?

Comment: The id is just a **number**, that R uses to uniquely identify the components in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the ID of any view by using `View.getId()`, though it will simply be an `int`. This can be useful when you want to do the following:

```
if(img.getId() == R.id.imageView1) {
    ...
}
```

You cannot, however, retrieve the name of the picture file that was used to populate the `ImageView`.

If you want additional info in an `ImageView` (or any `View`) you can set the view's *tag*...

```
<ImageView
...
android:tag="ThisIsMyTag"
... />
```

...and retrieve the tag in your code:

```
String myImageTag = img.getTag();
```

Comment: I am a bit confused because I have a drawable R.drawable.picture_1; and the I set    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture_1); but when I compare this img.getId() to R.drawable.picture_1, I have not the same value , WHY ?